# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.MetricsWindow'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x

what is this error please help me iam getting it in python & iam new ? iam using the open source code of simso simulator

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.MetricsWindow'; '**main**' is not a package

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and the full traceback error.

Answer (score 0):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.MetricsWindow'; '__main__' is not a package` may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `__main__.py` and try to run it as `python __main__.py` or another file has the name `__main__.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.